# n-th child on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

On this site:

http://c3.finearts.txstate.edu

I styled the right sidebar navigation using:

---

```
.sidenav a:after {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -3.6em;
    left: 0.15em;
    width: 90%;
    content: ".";
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', helvetica, arial, sans-serif !important;      
    font-size:1.5em;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    padding-left:0.7em;
    margin-bottom:1.16em;
    background-color: rgba(51,50,48,0.9);
    background-image: url('http://uweb.txstate.edu/~j_f166/codepen/images/notch.png');
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;     
}

.sidenav a:nth-child(n+2) li{
  margin-top: -4.4em;
}
```

---

In Firefox 3.6.17 it renders like this:

http://www.browserstack.com/start#os=Windows&os_version=7&browser=Firefox&browser_version=3.6&zoom_to_fit=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fc3.finearts.txstate.edu&resolution=1024x768&speed=2

(it only takes a moment to load...I'm a newbie here so I can't post a screenshot).

although according to caniuse
these pseudo-classes should be supported starting with 3.5.

As an added hassle, I am using our university's content managements system. It's a Magnolia system. I am 99% positive I can't alter the head to insert javascript.

So three questions:

Is there a css fix I can use to get these pseudo-classes working in this and nearby Firefox version?

Is there a polyfill?

If so, where can I insert such a polyfill given that I don't have access to the html head?

Thanks a bunch. Of course I just noticed this (it didn't show up in BrowserShots and I just happened upon it when doing random testing on colleague's machines). The site is to go live to the University tomorrow.

Yay,

Jill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue has something to do with Firefox 3.6 not liking how you have li tags inside anchors inside ul tags, not your CSS.  It seems to be trying to automatically fix your markup structure, which is then breaking your CSS.

Take a look a the following screenshot from FF 3.6 and you'll see that your anchor tags are being duplicated:

## FF 3.6

[image]

---

Now take a look at this screen shot from Chrome where I've recreated the erroneous markup that FF 3.6 is rendering:

## Chrome

[image]

This COULD be an issue with how your CMS is serving markup to FF 3.6 but I doubt it.  My money is on FF seeing un-semantic markup and trying to "fix" it for you.

If you absolutely had to keep the markup that you're using, then you could try looking for CSS hacks for firefox 3.6, or even use a browser sniffing library like [WhichBrowser](https://github.com/WhichBrowser/WhichBrowser).

However, I would recommend tweaking your CSS to work with markup that looks more like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Some browsers will try to "fix" your markup for you if it's not organized in a way that it was expecting, and this structure is more semantic.

Comment: Wild. So it seems that FF3.6 is changing the HTML to ensure that the anchor tags are not spanning the list tags? Is that not fair game to ensure that the entire button is active as opposed to just the text? I did that so that on mobile, the larger area is active.

Comment: That said, I think I will try the entire navigation without using lists. Honestly, I don't like using lists as navigation, but there is a majority on my team that insists on it.

Comment: Though maybe it's unsemantic to have an anchor tag spanning a div. Where might I find out these things?

Comment: I changed the list elements to divs and it works great on FF!

Comment: But it looks kinda crappy on i.e. 9 - 11. Livable though.

Comment: For the most part, semantics in HTML just means "match your tags to your content." A ton of devs and designers like to use lists for navigation because they see navbars as a list of navigation items. This is neither right nor wrong. Many discussions of semantics will turn into an un-winnable argument simply because so much of it is a matter of opinion. Some people are anal about doing things a certain way. In the real world, though, sometimes you just have to stick your pages together with duct tape.